PostgreSQL taking too long to run Update query fired through FastAPI Post API compared to DBeaver
I am encountering a performance issue with a FastAPI POST API that calls the below mentioned function. Specifically, two UPDATE queries executed at the end of the function are taking an unusually long time to run—approximately 200 to 600 seconds. However, when I execute the same queries directly in DBeaver, they complete in under a second. Upon further inspection, I found that almost all the delay occurs during the execution of the first UPDATE query, while the second query runs quickly, typically within a second. The data in the tables is within a few 100k entries with upto 20 fields.


def run_score_processing(rule_config, connection, run_id, config_id, source_table_name, line_item_table_name, header_table_name):

    if rule_config:
        # In this function, 4 "INSERT...ON CONFLICT" queries are being fired, running within a couple of seconds 
        po_score_processing(connection, run_id, config_id, source_table_name, line_item_table_name, header_table_name)

        query = text(f'''
                        UPDATE {header_table_name} hts
                            SET 
                                transaction_rft_by_engine = true,
                                flag_by_audit = 'unassigned'
                            FROM 
                                {line_item_table_name} lits
                            WHERE 
                                hts.base_id = lits.header_base_id
                                AND hts.stage = lits.stage
                                AND hts.run_id = lits.run_id
                                AND hts.config_id = {config_id}
                                AND lits.rft_by_engine = true;
                    ''')
       
        connection.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        
        query = text(f'''       
                        WITH aggregated_data AS(
                                SELECT 
                                    hts_inner.transaction_id AS header_id,
                                    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM COALESCE(hts_inner.header_rule_ids, '') || ',' || COALESCE(STRING_AGG(DISTINCT lits.rule_ids, ','), '')) AS rule_ids,
                                    hts_inner.price + SUM(lits.price) AS price,
                                    hts_inner.people + SUM(lits.people) AS people,
                                    hts_inner.process + SUM(lits.process) AS process,
                                    hts_inner.risk_score + sum(lits.risk_score) as risk_score
                                FROM 
                                    {header_table_name} hts_inner
                                LEFT JOIN 
                                    {line_item_table_name} lits 
                                ON 
                                    hts_inner.base_id = lits.header_base_id 
                                    AND hts_inner.config_id = lits.config_id
                                    AND hts_inner.stage = lits.stage
                                    AND hts_inner.run_id = lits.run_id
                                WHERE 
                                    hts_inner.transaction_rft_by_engine = true 
                                    AND hts_inner.config_id = {config_id}
                                GROUP BY 
                                    hts_inner.transaction_id,
                                    hts_inner.header_rule_ids,
                                    hts_inner.price,
                                    hts_inner.people,
                                    hts_inner.process,
                                    hts_inner.risk_score
                                )
                        UPDATE {header_table_name} hts
                            SET 
                                rule_ids = agg.rule_ids,
                                price = agg.price,
                                people = agg.people,
                                process = agg.process,
                                risk_score = agg.risk_score
                            FROM aggregated_data agg
                            WHERE 
                                hts.transaction_id = agg.header_id;
                    ''')
       
        connection.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        print(f"Rule ID's, 3P's and Risk Score updated in header transaction summary in {runtime} seconds")

        print(f"Line Item RFT to Header Level RFT set!")


    else:
        print("*******************Empty Rule Config!*******************")


Could this be due to resources being blocked or locked when the UPDATE query is executed within the API? If so, how can I debug and resolve this issue? Any guidance on understanding the discrepancy in performance between DBeaver and the FastAPI execution would be highly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!
To resolve this, I have tried the following approaches:

Created a stored procedure and called it through the python.
Created a fresh db connection specifically for the UPDATE queries.
Split the API into two separate endpoints—one handling the operations before the UPDATE queries and another dedicated to running just the UPDATE queries, hosted on separate ports.

Despite these changes, the issue persists.

Do they update about the same number of rows?  Use auto_explain to get a plan of the slow execution, with ANALYZE and BUFFERS options.
